# How to get the long and lat using the name of the state/city/etc ? [Android]

Tags: android, google-maps

I have some cars, and each car has a field "city" and a field "state",  I want to get the lat and long to search on google maps, in my app I'm already seeing my current location, but I want to see the car location, but all I can find is how to get the city name using the lat and long... How can I do this?
There is a way to search on google maps using only the name, without lat and long?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google Places API and send a text search request using the city and state as the query. It will return several pieces of information including the lat and long. Then just parse the JSON or XML to pull out the lat and long from the results.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should user the Android Geocoder class for achieving this.

You can use the function getFromLocationName() for this purpose. Do let me know if you have any problems implementing. The usage is very simple though.